# NoSQL Architecture White Papers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hadoop, rabbitmq

I want to better understand how technologies like RabbitMQ, MongoDb, Node.Js and Hadoop fit together into a system architecture to provide high-availability/scalability/performance.

Can anyone direct me to a good source for this sort of information?

EDIT

Admittedly, this isn't a great question, I should clarify.  I'm not looking for specifics on any of the techs in the above stack, I have an understanding of what each of them do and some knowledge of how to use them.  What I'm looking for is a specification for a system that leverage's message queue/NoSQL/Map reduce/event driven lang so I can better understand how they work together to deliver high-availability/scalability/performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you I would focus on the overall system design before focusing on specific technologies. RabbitMQ transports messages from place to place, MongoDB stores documents, Node.JS processes HTTP requests, and Hadoop stores & process data. Each of those systems has various competitors.

I'd check out [real life architectures from the highscalability.com blog](http://highscalability.squarespace.com/blog/category/example). I would also check out [the CAP paper](http://lpd.epfl.ch/sgilbert/pubs/BrewersConjecture-SigAct.pdf) that lays out what exactly "available" means.

Comment: Good answer to a poor question, I'll check those out, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you're asking for a general intro to NodeJS in the context of "Why should I use this instead of LAMP/Ruby/Python/$YourOldStackHere"

The only thing I can suggest is: watch a bunch of [nodeJS videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I), read http://nodebeginner.org, and develop a simple application to get a feel for it all.

As far as how they "fit together into a system architecture to provide high-availability/scalability/performance", well, they fit as you'd expect them to; Node provides a fast event-driven language, memcache/redis/mongo provides a (non)persistent key/value store which drops the relational aspect of SQL which many SQL-driven solutions don't actually need, and swaps it for speed.

"high-availability/scalability/performance" all boil down to how fast the tech is on your hardware. Fast things are more scalable, available, performant. NodeJS is built on V8 which is the fastest JS engine, but that doesn't really mean anything if you're comparing to eg PHP.

A quick google will surely provide some analyses of "node vs $YourStack"

Comment: "Fast things are more scalable, available..." - no, fast things are not more available. A very fast app running on one physical machine will still be unavailable if that machine loses power. A very slow app running on multiple machines in multiple data centers can be available even if a machine or data center dies.